# How Selenium getPageSource() work when we use switchTowindow is used?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What driver.getPageSource() method return if I switch the driver to some other window i have checked it is returning me the page source of the first page i.e. the first webpage I have launched how to get page source of current switched window..without relaunching the page....??

I have written the code like this I am successfully switching to the new window..but unable to get page source of current window...

```
public boolean switchToWindow(String title) 
{
    Set<String> availableWindows = webDr.getWindowHandles();        
    if (availableWindows.size() > 1) 
    {
        try 
        {
            for (String windowId : availableWindows) 
            {                   
                if(webDr.switchTo().window(windowId).getTitle().equals(title))
            {
              return true;
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.handleError("No child window is available to switch ", e);
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.getPageSource() should return the current active window source. From your code you can call driver.getPageSource() after switching to window.

```
public boolean switchToWindow(String title) 
{

    Set<String> availableWindows = webDr.getWindowHandles();        
    if (availableWindows.size() > 1) 
    {
        try 
        {
            for (String windowId : availableWindows) 
            {                   
                if(webDr.switchTo().window(windowId).getTitle().equals(title))
            {
              System.out.println(driver.getPageSource()); 
              return true;
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.handleError("No child window is available to switch ", e);
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Giri thanks for your response I have switched the driver first and successfully returned true from above function i.e. switchToWindow after that i have tried to get get the pageSource but getPageSource is returning me the page source of previous page only.